# Combing two queries while using group by

Tags: mysql, sql

Having some trouble figuring out the logic to this. See the two queries below:

Query 1:

```
SELECT cId, crId, COUNT(EventType)
FROM Data
WHERE EventType='0' OR EventType='0p' OR EventType='n' OR EventType = 'np'
GROUP BY crId;
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT cId, crId, COUNT(EventType) AS Clicks
FROM Data
WHERE EventType='c'
GROUP BY crId;
```

Was just wondering if there was a way to make the column that I would get at the end of query 2 appear in query 1. Since the where statements are different, not really sure where to go, and any subquery that I've wrote just hasn't worked.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Combining queries is possible via UNION statement construct

Comment: why don't you just add OR EventType = 'c' to the first query!!

Comment: Thanks everyone! Learned some nifty things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT cId, crId, 
SUM(CASE WHEN EventType='0' OR EventType='0p' OR EventType='n' OR EventType = 'np' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Count_1,
SUM(CASE WHEN EventType='c' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Count_2
FROM Data
WHERE EventType IN ('0','0p','n','np','c')
GROUP BY crId;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can join the two, using the second as a correlated subquery.

```
SELECT 
  Data.cId, 
  Data.crId, 
  COUNT(EventType) AS event_type_count,
  click_counts.Clicks
FROM 
  Data
  /* Correlated subquery retrieves the Clicks (EventType 'c') per cId */
  LEFT JOIN  (
    SELECT cId, crId, COUNT(EventType) AS Clicks
    FROM Data
    WHERE EventType='c'
    GROUP BY crId
  ) AS click_count ON Data.cId = click_count.cId AND Data.crId = click_count.crId
/* OR chain replaced with IN() clause */
WHERE Data.EventType IN ('0','0p','n','np')
/* This GROUP BY should probably also include Data.cId... */
GROUP BY Data.crId;
```

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't sure if I should declare what table it was since I was only using 1 table. Should I do that all the time?

Comment: @JonHagelin It doesn't matter which table you reference in the `SELECT` list where the column is common to both, but you must include either the main table or the subquery alias to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: Sorry for the total newb questions, I'm just trying to understand the logic for future purposes, but why do we do the subquery in the from instead of the select? And what exactly is "Clicks" in the first Select?

Comment: Shouldn't you actually do a cross join? With different `WHERE` clauses one could assume, that the cIds of both queries are disjunct.

Comment: @JonHagelin I put in the alias `click_counts.Clicks` to make it more apparent - `Clicks` in that context is the value returned by the subquery.  Doing the subquery in the `SELECT` list causes it to be executed for _each_ row, which is super slow. This way the query gets executed only once and the result (probably stored in a temp table) joined against the outer query. It is usually much faster.

Comment: @tombom I just noticed the difference between `cId` and `crId`. By joining on _both_ of them instead of just `cId`, that should solve it.

Comment: You missed my point, pal. By doing an inner join with different where clauses in the queries it could be that there will be no result at all.

Comment: @tombom I see what you mean. For MySQL, we would need to join both against a list of `DISTINCT cId, crId`.  The `SUM(CASE)` solution is much better anyway, which is why you got my +1

Comment: Or a `left join`, yes. The OP actually didn't make that point clear enough. Anyway, +1 for a different solution, which might be better suited in different situations. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this all querying from the table once and using `CASE` statements.

```
SELECT  cId, crId, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN EventType IN ('0', '0p', 'n', 'np') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as events,
        SUM(CASE WHEN EventType = 'c' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as clicks
FROM    Data
WHERE   EventType IN ('0', '0p', 'n', 'np', 'c')
GROUP BY crId;
```

Comment: +1 I was just adding this to my answer. You shouldn't need the `WHERE` clause though.

Comment: @Michael - I left the `WHERE` clause in because I wasn't sure if there were any other Event Types that were being excluded.  If those are all of the Event Types you're right, you could drop the WHERE clause altogether.

Comment: but because EventTypes not listed in either of those cases results in a 0, they don't get counted anyway.

Comment: That's true, the results will be the same either way.  I generally prefer to filter out records I'm not going to look at hoping that performance is better.  However not knowing what the data looks like, indexing, etc. it's hard to tell which way would work better.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `IN`?

```
SELECT cId, crId, COUNT(EventType) as Clicks
FROM Data 

WHERE EventType IN ('0','0p','n','np','c') 
GROUP BY crId;
```

---

:) PUtting myself in right direction ;)

[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6c059/7)

```
select id, crid, 
 count(case when type <> 'c' 
       then crid end) count_others,
 count(case when type ='c' 
       then crid end) count_c
 from tb
 group by crid
 ;
```

Comment: There should be 4 fields total. One COUNT(EventType) that counts all the occurrences of 0, 0p, n, and np. And then another column COUNT(EventType) that counts all the occurrences of c. Does that make any sense?

Comment: This is not what the OP wants

Comment: @JonHagelin oh well, first impression cheated me ;) sorry.

Comment: @JonHagelin I got myself correct ;) Anyway it's a nice question +1. You may add the last `where clause with in` if you have many other types in the system than the ones you have pointed out here. in mys sample table i only used those.. so didnt make much difference.